# Insert an operator in a method

Tags: javascript, methods, operators

The task is to write a function **interpret(arr, operator)** that gets an array and reduces it according to the **operator**.

The obvious solution is:

```
function interpret(arr, operator) {

    switch (operator) {
        case '+' :
            return arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b);
        case '-':
            return arr.reduce((a, b) => a - b);
        case '*':
            return arr.reduce((a, b) => a * b);
        case '/':
            return arr.reduce((a, b) => a / b);
        default:
            throw new Error(`No such command: ${operator}!`);
    }
}
```

What I don't like is that almost the same expression is repeated 4 times.

A solution immediately comes to mind:

```
function interpret(arr, operator) {
    return eval(`arr.reduce((a, b) => a ${operator} b)`)
}
```

Is there a way to insert the function argument **operator** in the **reduce()** method other than the strictly deprecated **eval()**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about the question, but you could put all those `case`s in the reduce, instead of before reduce.

```
function interpret(arr, operator) {
   return arr.reduce((a, b) => {
     switch (operator) {
       case '+' :
         return a+b;
       case '-' :
         return a-b;
       case '*' :
         return a*b;
       case '/' :
         return a/b;
       default:
         throw new Error(`No such command: ${operator}!`)
     }
   })
}
```

Comment: This is a pretty good solution, and so far the most suitable one for me. But I will clarify the question: is it possible in javascript to insert the string from variable (like operator = '+', ' * ' or '* * ') in any methods or expressions - that is, to use them as an operator rather than as a string? I quite admit that this possibility simply does not exist. (Of course except for eval())

Comment: I've found that you can also do `new Function('return ' + String(a) + operator + String(b))()` (so use `new Function(code)` and call it). I know that `eval` is risky (security issues) and slow. This one is for sure risky too, not sure how the speed looks.

Comment: Anyway - I would advise NOT to use any of those. You are getting security risk in the price of few lines of code. It's really not worth it :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a static operation each time, try passing a function, i.e, the callback itself for the reduce function. Something like this.

```
function interpret(arr,operation){
    return arr.reduce(operation)
}
```

You can then call it as

```
arr = [3, 3, 546]

interpret(arr, (res,val)=>res+val) //552
interpret(arr, (res,val)=>res*val) // 4914
```

Now you can pass whatever you want. Like modulo or power or so.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But under the conditions of the task we need to **take** the operator as an argument of the function, and then reduce it depending on it. If it was possible to pass on this operator like: **(res,val)=>res${+}val** - this would be great, but other than using eval() to do this I have no idea how, which is exactly my question.

Comment: @Buria13 so in that case your piece of code seems good and wont be an issue in terms of performance. You ll not even have static code like that.